# How to insert unknown charset string to MariaDB table in C

Tags: mysql, c, mariadb

My sample code is..
`insert into test set fir='aaa',sec='¿¬ºA¦ µµT °¥µ젰ވ­.alz' (in C)`

This string copy&paste to MariaDB prompt, then success.

#### question

- but not work in C code. *sec* column is NULL. why?
- How can I modify this in C code that insert to DB? (It is okay to string is broken.)

MariaDB status...

```
MariaDB [oops]> status  
 ....  
Server characterset: utf8  
Db     characterset: utf8  
Client characterset: utf8  
Conn.  characterset: utf8  
...  
MariaDB [oops]> show full columns from test  
...  
| fir | varchar(255) | utf8_general_ci |  
| sec | varchar(255) | utf8_general_ci |  
...
```

thanks.

Ps.
C code is parse character(`¿¬ºA¦ µµT °¥µ젰ވ­.alz`) in E-Mail

#### add

```
MariaDB [oops]> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                         |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                          |
| character_set_connection | utf8                          |
| character_set_database   | utf8                          |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                        |
| character_set_results    | utf8                          |
| character_set_server     | utf8                          |
| character_set_system     | utf8                          |
| character_sets_dir       | /xxxx/mysql/share/charsets/   |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [oops]>
```

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

Comment: What parameters were used when connecting from C?

Comment: If it's an unknown charset string, then is it really a string?

Comment: @RickJames James what's mean? mysql_real_connect() this?

Comment: @immibis what a string or?

Comment: @BaekJae-Yeon A string is a sequence of characters, is it not? If you have a sequence of bytes and you know they represent characters, but you don't know the encoding, then you don't know what the characters are. Like asking how to insert an "unknown base number".

Comment: And if you don't know the encoding, you are likely to get in trouble with `TEXT` or `VARCHAR`.  If you use `BLOB`, instead, the you still have not solved the display problem.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql C client often defaults to a latin1 client connection while the mysql command line client adopts the character set of the user's environment.

So my guess would be that if you execute "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'" from within your C program, you'll get a row back stating that the client connection is in fact latin1.

Thus, although the charset of your original string is "unknown" to you, it probably contains some multibye character sequences which are being wrongfully encoded as a result of inserting data from a latin1 client connection into a utf8 database/column.

Generally speaking, if you want your data to be unadulterated upon insertion then your client connection character encoding should match that of the database/column.